# How to take this limit involving Gamma function

Tags: calculus, limits, gamma-function

I need to check if the following limit is 1 or not.
$$\lim_{n, m \to \infty}\frac{\Gamma (n+m+2)}{\Gamma (n+m-x-y+1)}\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^1 p^{n}(1-p)^{n-x}q^{m-1}(1-q)^{m-y-1}dpdq=?$$

where $0<p,q<1$, $0<x<n$, and $0<y<m$.

Could anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Hint: The tow integrals seperate and can be calculated in terms of gamma functions

Comment: Afterwards apply stirling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Fubini's Theorem,
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 p^{n}(1-p)^{n-x}q^{m-1}(1-q)^{m-y-1}dp\,dq
&= \left( \int_0^1 p^n (1-p)^{n-x}\,dp \right) \left(\int_0^1 q^{m-1}(1-q)^{m-y-1}\,dq \right) \\
&= \mathrm{B}(n+1,n-x+1) \mathrm{B}(m,m-y) 
\end{align*}$$
where $\mathrm{B}$ is the [B Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). It has a known identity
$$ \mathrm{B}(u,v) = \frac{\Gamma(u)\Gamma(v)}{\Gamma(u + v)}
$$
Therefore,
$$ \mathrm{B}(n+1,n-x+1) \mathrm{B}(m,m-y)
= \frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n-x+1)\Gamma(m)\Gamma(m-y)}{\Gamma(2n - x + 2)\Gamma(2m - y)}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the simplification.But I am still having problem with taking limit with the gamma function. the result is 0 or infinity?. it seems that the last term that you wrote down goes to zero as n and m goes to infinity. and it seems that the ratio of the gamma functions above in the original question goes to Infinity as n and m goes to infinity .Hence I am getting the result as 0*infinity.I dont know what should I do for getting the correct result.do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Jimmy Dur As someone in the comment(Sorry, can't notify two at a time) suggested, use Stirling's approximation.

Comment: oh I have just seen this comment.Thanks again.